# Maven, spring, tomcat7: What do I need in pom.xml to deploy correctly?

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

file pom.xml has the following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
  <!-- MySQL Driver -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.35</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- spring -->    
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>           
  </dependency>    
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <type>jar</type>
  </dependency>    
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <type>jar</type>
  </dependency>    

  <!-- JSTL -->    
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2-rev-1</version>      
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>fmt</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
    <type>tld</type>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And the following plugin:

```
  <plugins>            

    <!-- tomcat -->
    <plugin>  
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>  
      <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
      <version>2.2</version>  
      <configuration>  
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
        <username>admin</username>  
        <password>admin</password>
      </configuration>  
    </plugin>  
  </plugins>
```

The deploy gives me the error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) on project spring_addressbook: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection reset -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) on project spring_addressbook: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
...
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
```

I'm using Apache Maven 3.0.5 and Apache Tomcat 7. I think dependencies are ok, and I'm not sure about plugins.
And I'm using Netbeans.

tomcat-users.xml:

```
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-script,manager-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Answer (score 0):

One user should not have both manager-gui and manager-script roles.

Create two users:

```
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-script"/>
<user username="admin_gui" password="admin" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

Also, you could try specifying path in plugin configuration

```
 <configuration>  
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
        <username>admin</username>  
        <password>admin</password>
        <path>/myAppName</path>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: I've seen both kind of configurations, anyway I will try both. thanks.